# Regex with sed using quotation mark

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I need to change part of text in my file. I try to write a script in bash for update my PATH which contains other/old JAVA_HOME. My regex should find part of text which contains path like below and change it with sed command.

> /**/jdk/jdk.*/bin

I made regex on:

- https://regexr.com/

  > ([/])[^/]*([/]jdk[/]jdk).*?([/]bin)
- https://regex101.com/

  > (/)[^/]*(/jdk/jdk).*?(/bin)

.**bash_env**

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_151" 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:example/not/for/change/bin"
```

**expected output**

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_151" 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:CHANGED:example/not/for/change/bin"
```

**sed command**

```
sed -r 's#([/])[^\/]*([/]jdk[/]jdk).*?([/]bin)#CHANGED#g' ~/.bash_env
```

**Question**
I tried a lot of variations with my sed and regex but it doesn't work or change all paths without stopping on first /bin. I think it's problem with questions mark but maybe someone can give me an advice ? Or help with write regex for sed?

**UPDATE.1**
Example when my solution doesn't work

**example .bash_env**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/example/not/jdk/for/change/bin"
```

**my sed**

```
sed -r 's#([/])[^\/]*([/]jdk[/]jdk).*?([/]bin)#CHANGED#g' ~/.bash_env
```

**given result**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:CHANGED"
```

**expected result**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:CHANGED:/example/not/jdk/for/change/bin"
```

Regex (with sed) should change word which:
- starts with '/'
- doesn't contain ':'
- contains 'jdk/jdk'
- ends with '/bin'

Comment: have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: Can you provide a sample for which it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this sed

```
echo $PATH | sed 's/\([^:]*\)/CHANGED/8'
```

I think the search path isn't always at the same place so try this one.

```
echo $PATH | sed 's#\(.*\)\(:/.*jdk[^:]*\)\(:.*\)#\1:CHANGED\3#'
```

You can test this one :

```
 echo $path | sed 's#\(.*\)\(:*\)\(/.*/jdk/jdk[0-9._]*/bin\)\(:*\)\(.*\)#\1\2CHANGED\4\5#'
```

I try with the start position, with the end position and in the middle.

Comment: Thanks ! But it only works for specific cases, not for all my rules.